# android translucent Dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog

How can I configure Dialog layout so that the Dialog is displayed as translucent (with color and alpha channel set to some 50% so that the overlayed view is visible through the Dialog). 
I create a custom Dialog and set the contentView to be simple TextView only. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, somehow, this is what you might find usefull:

```
final Dialog d = new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use setFeatureDrawableAlpha()
See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setFeatureDrawableAlpha(int, int)

Comment: What to put for featureId parameter in order to have entire content of dialog translucent?

Comment: setFeatureDrawableAlpha() seems not to be working no matter what parameter I provide as featureId.